# How can I stop Python's Requests library from stripping out escape characters?

Tags: json, node.js, python-requests

I am receiving a block of JSON that looks like this (edited for brevity):

```
... "actions": [{"script": \"{\"inputs\": [], <LOTS MORE JSON>}"}]"
```

Essentially it's a string nested inside another object.

When I send this JSON to my Node.js API using something Advanced Rest Client in Chrome, it succeeds. When I send it using this Python code, however:

```
headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}
newrsp = self.session.post("http://my-api", data=str(my_json), headers=headers)
```

I receive

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token i
```

Looking at the body before JSON.parse is called, it appears that my payload has been modified. Instead of looking like this:

```
... "actions": [{"script": \"{\"inputs\": [], <LOTS MORE JSON>}"}]"''
```

it looks like this:

```
... "actions": [{"script": "{"inputs": [], <LOTS MORE JSON>}"}]"
```

Calling my API from other programs works and doesn't remove the escape characters, so I'm pretty confident that it's not my code, but the Requests API is stripping out the characters somehow before it sends my JSON.

I'm not a Pythonista by an stretch... any Python people out there know what's going on (and hopefully a way I can tell requests not to do this)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question, in case someone has a similar problem...

It looks like the requests API has some automatic conversion routine that strips off JSON escape characters from elements that don't need it. I ended up calling json.dumps on the piece of JSON that was having issue BEFORE assembling the entire long string (and calling json.dumps again when passing to requests). This effectively 'double-encoded' it, so when requests stripped off escape characters, it left it the way I wanted it.

Answer (score 7):

If you use the argument "data" you should convert by yourself the JSON:

```
jsonItem = json.dumps(dict(item))
req = requests.post('http://...', data=jsonItem)
```

If you use the argument "json" you delegate the conversion:

```
req = requests.post('http://...', json=dict(item))
```