# Prevent automatic stripping of quotes in url

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to get the contents of this url using the `requests` module in python but the quotes in the url which I need is being automatically stripped away.

Url looks similar to:

```
https://www.mypage.com/graphql/query/?query_id=123&variables={"id":1111,"first":10}
```

but when i make the request, the params part of the url automatically becomes

```
?query_id=123&variables={id:1111,first:10}
```

I need the quotes surrounding the `id` and `first`. Is there a way to fix this because it doesn't work even if I encode the url.

> PS: Please, don't just give a negative rating without reason, explanation or offering help. It's not my first time using python and I wouldn't post here if I haven't tried all the options I have.

Comment: Not sure but maybe this will fix your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35049736/how-can-i-stop-pythons-requests-library-from-stripping-out-escape-characters

Comment: when I try this with [httpbin.org/get](http://httpbin.org) then it show me that portal gets query with `"` - so there is no problem. Maybe create minimal working example which still have this problem. And show real url which needs this data.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using "URL" encoding?

In your case replacing `"` with `%22`could help.

See also https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp for reference.

Comment: Did you also try to escape them? And/or did you try @Fatih Kılıç answer?

Comment: yep. doesn't work. I've tried many things before posting the question

Comment: Strange. 
Maybe as a workaround you could catch those fields and add the quotes before processing the request.

Comment: Another thing you could do to limit failure sources: try using _double_ double-quotes and/or just single quotes. And also url encode the entire string.

Comment: I've even used string substitution, url parsing and encoding but no solution.